# Retrive Redis record based on the one of it's fields

Tags: rust, redis

I know that redis doesn't use "Records" and "Fields" but i found this to be the best way of describing this. Basically i have the following schema:

```
"SESSION_ID": {
    "user_id": String,
}
```

All i wish to do is get all sessions that have a specific user_id, i haven't really been able to find anything on this yet. (Note that in this case we do not know the session_id only the user_id)

I've tried using `smembers` and such but i am a beginner with redis so i don't really have much.

Answer (score 0):

Redis has secondary indexing with [RediSearch](https://redis.io/docs/interact/search-and-query/). It can index hashes and JSON objects, and let you perform search queries over your keys.

You didn’t give a lot of information, but I assume you have some session object that has a `user_id` attribute. Here is an example using hashes:

```
HSET session:123 user_id 42 more_data value …
FT.CREATE idx ON HASH PERFIX 1 session: SCHEMA user_id NUMERIC …
FT.SEARCH idx "@user_id:[42 42]"
```

This commands will create a hash for session 123, then an index named idx for indexing sessions, with a numeric attribute named user_id, and lastly perform a search on this index to retrieve all the hashes that has user_id value in the range [42 42] (so it’s an exact match for 42).

There are many other field types you can use, and there is support for the search (and JSON) set of commands in most of the redis clients, including the Python, nodeJS, PHP and more